# creating new vector of different strings

Tags: r

New to R so not really sure what I'm looking, but I guess purrr could do this for me.

How could I create this vector:

```
c <- c("cookie", "cookie", "cookie", "cookie", "dog", "dog", "dog")
```

from this:

```
a <- 4
b <- 3
```

Comment: Do you need `rep(c("cookie", "dog"), c(4, 3))` ?

Comment: Yes, that was quick, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `rep`

```
rep(c("cookie","dog"),c(a,b))
```